# rails interact with 3rd party API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, redmine

My app often needs to work with 3rd party API and use a lot of data from response, **redmine** is one of them.(maybe will use **3~4** 3rd API) 
I tried to use **Net::HTTP**, for example:

my controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def get_request (request)
    uri = URI.parse(request)
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  end
end

require 'net/http'
class LogsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        redmine_api_key = 'key=' + 'my key'
        redmine_api_url = 'http://redmine/users/1.json?'
        request_user = redmine_api_url + redmine_api_key
        @user_get = get_request(request_user)
        @user_data = JSON.parse(@user_get.body)['user']
    end
end
```

my view:(just test to show what I got)

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <h1>Account data</h1>

  <%= @user_data %><br>

  <%= @user_get.code %><br>
  <%= @user_get.message %><br>
  <%= @user_get.class.name %><br>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>login</th>
        <th>firstname</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
        <th>mail</th>
        <th>created_on</th>
        <th>last_login_on</th>
        <th>api_key</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><%= @user_data['id'] %></td>
            <td><%= @user_data['login'] %></td>
            <td><%= @user_data['firstname'] %></td>

            <td><%= @user_data['custom_fields'][0]['id'] %></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody> 
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can get data what I want, but I don't know my method is right or stupid(**I mean some code like JSON.parse(@user_get.body)['user']**). 
I do some research, in some article, they said: if app work with multiple API, write in **lib folder** is a better way. 
And some body suggested: get all data from 3rd API and **create own DB** to manage data.
But I can't find a complete tutorial about how to work with 3rd party API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may need to do API calls to the 3rd party often. You can write that code in the `lib` folder.
In `Api.rb`

```
module Api

def self.do_get_request(url, params={})
  request = request + '?' + params.to_query
  uri = URI.parse(request)
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  JSON.parse(response) if response
end
```

Now in you controller you can call this function:

```
require 'net/http'
class LogsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        params = {key: 'my key'}
        redmine_api_url = 'http://redmine/users/1.json'
        response = Api.do_get_request(redmine_api_url, params)
        @user_data = response['user'] if response.present?
    end
end
```

The `do_get_request` can be a general function. You can also create 3rd party specific functions in API module in lib, then you won't have to add the key at the end of every request.
Whatever be the response you would always parse it using JSON.parse, hence that code can be pushed to the Api Module.

If you are frequenty using this data you can store this in your database. For that you would have to create a model (Read rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: thanks a lot! appreciated your suggestion, I will study document more seriously.